# what is a dubious test in casperjs

Tags: casperjs

When running a test getting.

```
FAIL 35 tests executed in 16.806s, 35 passed, 0 failed, 2 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

What does the 'dubious' imply and how to see which assertion or test case is dubious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the dubious tests are those that aren't run because of failed tests.

So if the test case tried to exit after a failed test, but there were still 2 tests that were meant to be run after it, those 2 tests would be considered dubious.

Afaik, there is no way to see which tests are dubious because CasperJS just uses the number of passed/failed tests out of the specified number of tests to get that number.

You shouldn't consider a dubious test as either a pass or as a fail because there is no way to know which way the test would have gone.

Comment: RoshanMJ is right. Dubious is defined in modules/tester.js around line 1156. Check this: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/4afe11024a23183cb33a4d95f803873b8898c951/modules/tester.js

Answer (score 30):

Dubious tests occurs when there is mismatch in the number of tests (`x`) passed as argument to Casperjs test instance `casper.test.begin('sometest',x,function(){...})` and the number of actual tests in the file.

In essence, the number of planned tests (`x`) should be equal to the number of executed tests.

Answer (score 1):

In your tests, change the 'X' (see below) to the number of assertions you have inside it and then you will see no more debiuous

```
casper.test.begin('sometest',X,function(){...})
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @RoshanMJ is correct, however, each time we create new assertions, we have to update `X` number.

I just remove the **`X`** parameter in `casper.test.begin('sometest',X,function(){...})` and it will work, like this:

```
casper.test.begin('sometest',function(){...})
```